# HTML span align center not working?

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML:

```
<div align="center" style="border:1px solid red">
This is some text in a div element!
</div>
```

The Div is changing the spacing on my document, so I want to use a span for this instead.

But span is not centralizing the contents:

```
<span style="border:1px solid red;align=center">
This is some text in a div element!
</span>
```

How do I fix this?

EDIT:

My complete code:

```
<html>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph. This text has no alignment specified.</p>

<span style="border:1px solid red;text-align=center">
  This is some text in a div element!
</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your div is "changing the spacing"? What do you mean by this? And your span won't because by default it's an _inline_ element, whereas a div is a _block_ level element.

Comment: Hello JamWaffles, By "spacing" I mean the div adds space above and below the contents.  The span does not do this.

Comment: Use Firebug or the Chrome inspector to see what CSS rules are applied to your element, and look for the one that adds padding or margin. It's also possible the surrounding elements have padding/margin.

Comment: `text-align=center` should be `text-align:center`

Answer (score 240, accepted):

A div is a block element, and will span the width of the container unless a width is set. A span is an inline element, and will have the width of the text inside it. Currently, you are trying to set align as a CSS property. Align is an attribute.

```
<span align="center" style="border:1px solid red;">
    This is some text in a div element!
</span>
```

However, the align attribute is deprecated. You should use the CSS `text-align` property on the container.

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <span style="border:1px solid red;">
        This is some text in a div element!
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with the 2nd method comes when the container should left-aligned, and then some text inside it should be centered. Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438339/how-may-i-align-text-to-the-left-and-text-to-the-right-in-the-same-line). I tried the deprecated method since it seems the only way, but it doesn't work in Chroimum nor in Firefox.

Answer (score 64):

Please use the following style. `margin:auto` normally used to center align the content. `display:table` is needed for `span` element

```
<span style="margin:auto; display:table; border:1px solid red;">
    This is some text in a div element!
</span>
```

Comment: display table works in bootstrap 4 input group addon span

Answer (score 43):

The `align` attribute is deprecated. Use CSS `text-align` instead. Also, the span will not center the text unless you use `display:block` or `display:inline-block` and set a value for the width, but then it will behave the same as a div (block element).

Can you post an example of your layout? Use www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Can't I align two inline elements differently while keeping them inline elements?

Comment: The `display:block` [makes the text go to a new line](https://jsfiddle.net/hLj73a0t/1/). The `inline-block` doesn't work at all.

Comment: Yay, I found how to make it work, [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/4muyvL6c/). Basically, the solution is backwards: instead of centering the text you want to center, you left-aligning the text you want not to be in center. @JeffCamera do you mind adding a solution to your answer?

Answer (score 16):

```
span.login-text {
    font-size: 22px;
    display:table;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

<span class="login-text">Welcome To .....CMP</span>
```

For me it worked very well. try this also

Answer (score 3):

On top of all the other explanations, I believe you're using equal `"="` sign, instead of colon `":"`:

```
<span style="border:1px solid red;text-align=center">
```

It should be:

```
<span style="border:1px solid red;text-align:center">
```

Answer (score 1):

Span is inline-block and adjusts to inline text size, with a tenacity that blocks most efforts to style out of inline context. To simplify layout style (limit conflicts), add div to 'p' tag with line break.

```
<p> some default stuff
<br>
<div style="text-align: center;"> your entered stuff </div>
```

Answer (score -10):

Just use `word-wrap:break-word;` in the css. It works.