# How may I align text to the left and text to the right in the same line?

Tags: html, css

How can I align text so that some of it aligns to the left and some of it aligns to the right within the same line?

```
<p>This text should be left-aligned. This text should be right aligned.</p>
```

I can align all of the text to the left (or to the right), either directly inline, or by using a stylesheet -

```
<p style='text-align: left'>This text should be left-aligned. 
    This text should be right aligned.</p>
```

How can I align the corresponding text to the left and to the right, while keeping it on the same line?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

```html
<p style="text-align:left;">
    This text is left aligned
    <span style="float:right;">
        This text is right aligned
    </span>
</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/5z3ec48r/

Comment: `text-align:left;` it should be `float:left;` like <p>
    <span style="float:left;">
     Left text
    </span>
    <span style="float:right;">
     Right Text
    </span>
   </p>

Answer (score 45):

​HTML:

```
<span class="right">Right aligned</span><span class="left">Left aligned</span>​
```

css:

```
.right{
    float:right;
}

.left{
    float:left;
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/W3Pxv/1

Comment: @mawg Though it might be, I prefer the top answer because it doesn't require css.

Comment: Currently "on top" or "most votes"? Both of those can change, so you are not helping any future reaers :-)  Anyway, while I started like you, with all styling in-line, I soon realized that there are good reasons for separating content & presentation . CSS isn't scary & there are plenty of free tutorials around - go for it

Answer (score 27):

If you don't want to use floating elements and want to make sure that both blocks do not overlap, try:

```
<p style="text-align: left; width:49%; display: inline-block;">LEFT</p>
<p style="text-align: right; width:50%;  display: inline-block;">RIGHT</p>
```

Comment: This is the only answer that allows you to use more than just two columns, which was what I needed.  It's probably more granular control than the OP cared about though.

Answer (score 24):

An answer using css flex layout and justify-content

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>This text is left aligned</span>
  <span>This text is right aligned</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! I expected there to be a flex-box solution but not one so succinct!

Comment: This is the best solution for me because it works also in list, like this: https://catalin.red/css3-ordered-list-styles/ that I use for pinout description. See https://imgur.com/a/4YsPl5K

Answer (score 9):

HTML FILE:

```
<div class='left'> Left Aligned </div> 
<div class='right'> Right Aligned </div>
```

CSS FILE:

```
.left
{
  float: left;
}

.right
{
  float: right;
}
```

and you are done ....

Comment: This is old but you have to surround the 2 DIVs with another tag like a DIV or it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

While several of the solutions here will work, none handle overlap well and end up moving one item to below the other. If you are trying to layout data that will be dynamically bound you won't know until runtime that it looks bad.

What I like to do is simply create a single row table and apply the right float on the second cell. No need to apply a left-align on the first, that happens by default. This handles overlap perfectly by word-wrapping.

**HTML**

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr><td>Left aligned stuff</td>
      <td class="alignRight">Right aligned stuff</td></tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.alignRight {
  float: right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/esoyke/7wddxks5/

Comment: This is close to golden for me, but any idea why using the CSS table properties makes the two cells out of line horizontally? https://jsfiddle.net/7wddxks5/7/ I can't seem to get around it.

Comment: Actually, for me, since I want the right text aligned to the right, this seems to work perfectly if I simply assign text-align: right and get rid of the float.

Comment: I couldn't figure out why it was causing the vertical shifting either. But I was able to fix it with vertical-align. Also pulled the styles into classes to clean up the HTML a bit. https://jsfiddle.net/o10ogqkd

Comment: this is an elegant solution here. I think it should be the accepted answer as it employs more creativity in using the table tag

Answer (score 7):

```
<h1> left <span> right </span></h1>
```

css:

```
h1{text-align:left; width:400px; text-decoration:underline;}
span{float:right; text-decoration:underline;}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add span on each or group of words you want to align left or right. 
then add id or class on the span such as:

```
<h3>
<span id = "makeLeft"> Left Text</span>
<span id = "makeRight"> Right Text</span>
</h3>
```

CSS-

```
#makeLeft{
float: left;
}

#makeRight{
float: right;
}
```

Comment: Per the html spec, your example should use a class and not an ID.

Answer (score 2):

One example, only to show the richness of the solution from Benjamin Udink ten Cate in the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65323030/6266107): "An answer using css flex layout and justify-content"

With this CSS:

```css
    
p {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
#connettore{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px 20px 10px 180px;
    width: 250px;
    align:left;
}

ol#connettore {
    counter-reset: pin 6; /* Initiate a counter */
    list-style: none; /* Remove default numbering */
    /*list-style: decimal; /* Keep using default numbering for IE6/7 */
    font: 15px 'trebuchet MS', 'lucida sans';
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
ol ol {
    margin: 0 0 0 2em; /* Add some left margin for inner lists 20px*/
}    

/*=========== Rectangle-shaped numbers ===========*/
    
.rectangle-list a{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: .1em .2em .1em .8em;
    margin: .5em 0 .5em 2.5em;
    background: #ddd;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
    line-height: .1px;
    
}
.rectangle-list a:hover{
    background: #eee;
}
.rectangle-list a:before{
    content: counter(pin);
    counter-increment: pin -1;
    position: absolute;
    left: -2.5em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1em;
    background: #fa8072;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.rectangle-list a:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    border: .5em solid transparent;
    left: -1em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.5em;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
.rectangle-list a:hover:after{
    left: -.5em;
    border-left-color: #fa8072;
}
```

```html
<ol id="connettore" class="rectangle-list" >
    <li><a href=""><p><span>BLU</span> <span>(SWDIO)</span></p> </a> </li>
    <li><a href=""><p><span> MARRONE</span> <span>(SWDCLK)</span></p> </a></li>
    <li><a href=""><p><span>GIALLO</span> <span>(RESET)</span></p> </a></li>
    <li><a href=""><p><span>NERO</span> <span>(GND)</span></p> </a></li>
    <li><a href=""><p><span>BIANCO</span> <span>(VCC)</span></p> </a> </li>

</ol>
```

This is the way I do pinout. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="text-align:left">left align</div>
    <div class="col" style="text-align:right">right align</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to change alignment of text just make a classes

```
.left {
text-align: left;
}
```

and span that class through the text

```
<span class='left'>aligned left</span>
```

Comment: This is half the answer to the question of mutliple alignments per line.