# CSS right align being pushed to new line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a textbox that shows different values depending on the mouseover, I'd like the Name to be left aligned, and the corresponding value to the right aligned. I have the code close, but the tooltip is pushing the right-aligned text to a new line. Here is the CSS and the JS string variable, is there something off here?

```
.toolTip {
    font-family: arial;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    height: 130px;
    width: 390px;
    border: 1px solid #6F257F;
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
}  

.toolTip p.left {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.toolTip p.right {
    text-align: right;
}

var string = "<p class = 'left'>90-Day Actual Margin:  </p>" + "<p class = 'right'>12345</p>"
```

Here's a screenshot of what it currently looks like. 
[image: tooltip]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438339/how-may-i-align-text-to-the-left-and-text-to-the-right-in-the-same-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way, using `flexbox`

```
.toolTip {
    font-family: arial;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    height: 130px;
    width: 390px;
    border: 1px solid #6F257F;
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
}  

.toolTip div {
    display: flex;
}

.toolTip div p.left {
    flex: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
}

var string = "<div><p class = 'left'>90-Day Actual Margin:  </p>" + "<p class = 'right'>12345</p></div>"
```

```css
.toolTip {
        font-family: arial;
        position: absolute;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        height: 130px;
        width: 390px;
        border: 1px solid #6F257F;
        text-align: left;
        /*display: none;*/
    }  
    
    .toolTip div {
        display: flex;
    }
    
    .toolTip div p.left {
        flex: 1;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<div class="toolTip">
  <div>
    <p class = 'left'>90-Day Actual Margin:  </p>
    <p class = 'right'>12345</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

And here is another, using `float`

```
.toolTip {
    font-family: arial;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    height: 130px;
    width: 390px;
    border: 1px solid #6F257F;
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
}  

.toolTip p.left {
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.toolTip p.right {
    float: right;
}

.toolTip::after {     /* clearfix, to clear the floats */
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

var string = "<p class = 'left'>90-Day Actual Margin:  </p>" + "<p class = 'right'>12345</p>"
```

```css
.toolTip {
        font-family: arial;
        position: absolute;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        height: 130px;
        width: 390px;
        border: 1px solid #6F257F;
        text-align: left;
        /*display: none;*/
    }  
    
    .toolTip p.left {
        float: left;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .toolTip p.right {
        float: right;
    }

    .toolTip::after {     /* clearfix, to clear the floats */
        content: '';
        display: block;
        clear: both;
    }
```

```html
<div class="toolTip">
  <p class = 'left'>90-Day Actual Margin:  </p>
  <p class = 'right'>12345</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I used the first method and it worked great. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to align you heading "Oklahoma (40109" to the right, correct? You have to give and id to the header so you can change its position using CSS. In fact You have several options.

You can give to the tittle an id:

```
#heading {
        text-align: left;
}
```

If your heading is a child node of your div with attribute of class .toolTip you can do something like this:

```
.toolTip > h1 {
    text-align: left;
}
```

In order to have '90-Day Actual Margin:' and '12345' in the same line you have to do the following:

```
var string = "<p class ='left'>90-Day Actual Margin: " + "<span class="right">12345</span></p>"
```

or change your CSS to:

```
.toolTip p.left {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block
    float: left:
    position: relative;
}

.toolTip p.right {
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left:
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: The top line is centered as expected. The change I'd like is the "90 - Day" and "12345" to be on the same line.

Comment: that is something different

Answer (score 0):

make their (2 p elements)

```
display:inline;
```

it should solve the problem

Comment: I added this to both the `p` elements but it, unfortunately, made the whole thing left-aligned and there is only a single space between the Name and Value.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your css `width:` for both properties, and use `display:inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

Change the style of the p elements to:

```
display:inline-block;
```

And the right p element to:

```
float:right;
```

Complete line:

```
var string = "<p class = 'left' style='display:inline-block;'>90-Day Actual Margin:  </p> <p class = 'right' style='display:inline-block;float:right;'>12345</p>"
```