# Write one line with different align in Markdown

Tags: markdown

I'm writing resume and want to know how to use different aline in single line.

For example, I want to write that sentence

**ABC university** *Aug - Dec 2020*

how to right-align only my period (Aug-Dec 2020) without changing anything in ABC University

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How may I align text to the left and text to the right in the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438339/how-may-i-align-text-to-the-left-and-text-to-the-right-in-the-same-line)

Answer (score 4):

You have to use HTML. See [How may I align text to the left and text to the right in the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438339/how-may-i-align-text-to-the-left-and-text-to-the-right-in-the-same-line).

```
<p style="text-align:left;">
    **ABC university**
    <span style="float:right;">
        *Aug - Dec 2020*
    </span>
</p>
```

Test it here:

```html
<p style="text-align:left;">
    ABC university
    <span style="float:right;">
        Aug - Dec 2020
    </span>
</p>
```