# Align Unicode text left and right on the same line in HTML

Tags: html, css

How do I align some text on the left and other text on the right side of the same line?

I tried some solutions for non-Unicode text from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438339/how-may-i-align-text-to-the-left-and-text-to-the-right-in-the-same-line). But for Unicode text, the two parts of the text aren't vertically aligned:

[image: words "foo" and "foo" followed by full-width question mark are rendered in different heights]

```html
<div style="width: 70px;">
  <span style="float: left;">foo</span>
  <span style="float: right;">foo？</span>
</div>

<br><br>

<div style="width: 70px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
  <span>foo</span>
  <span>foo？</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Side note: for the "fullwidth question mark" character used in the snippet, Firefox on Windows picks "SimSun" (serif-y) font that has height optical metrics matching rest of the text (default Times New Roman) while Chrome picks "Microsoft YaHei" that is taller sans-serif-y and produces similar outcome as in the screenshot.

Comment: Could you try to add "align-items: baseline" CSS property in the 2. div's style? The other div should have the same styles with spans as well. They are being aligned vertically/horizontally

Comment: @OnurDoğan That seems like a pretty good suggestion, mind making it an answer? I think there is no solution for the "float" use-case, (I doubt there is a way to baseline-align float boxes of different height), but this solves the flex one.

Comment: @myf Yes, you are right. It fixes the second one. "Height" property could be added to the divs for managing the spaces between rows as well as I see. For "float" use-case, I think so too

Answer (score 1):

basically question mark is taking more space than fonts, giving line-height will solve the problem.. hope this helps..

```html
<div style="width: 70px;">
  <span style="float: left; line-height: 22px;">foo</span>
  <span style="float: right; line-height: 22px;">foo？</span>
</div>

<br><br>

<div style="width: 70px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
  <span style="line-height: 22px;">foo</span>
  <span style="line-height: 22px;">foo？</span>
</div>
```

Comment: OP's quesion mark is actually "fullwidth question mark" (https://graphemica.com/%EF%BC%9F) (not regular "?") and from their screenshot is seems that their user agent picks "wrong" front family with metrics that differ from the rest of the text.

Comment: How do I go with the default line height instead of hardcoding one (which might look bad depending on other CSS code)?

Comment: Problem is, in text block containing characters from two and more font families the "default" line height becomes the "sum" (distance from uppermost to lowermost em-box edge). See "Two ‘M’ glyphs" example at http://tavmjong.free.fr/blog/?p=1632 ("CSS Text Line Spacing Exposed!" article by Tavmjong Bah)