# Prevent text from shifting in Child of Flexbox Parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two elements within a flexbox container. One of these elements is a `Tag` I created. When the tag is within a flex container it appears to shift the text to the top of the `Tag`. How do I prevent this?

I've tried setting the parent container to `align-items: center;` which shrinks the `Tag`.

**HTML**

```html
<div>
  <span />
  <button>Resend</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

span {
  padding: 3px 4.8px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0.75rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: red;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: 0.25s ease;
  color: blue;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  font-size: .857142rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

**IMAGE**

[image]

Comment: The code you included doesn't fully recreate the problem. Please include everything in a code snippet embedded into your post that recreates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What appears to be happening is that the span element is increasing the bottom padding to match the total height of the button element that is next to it. One fix to this solution is to add `display:table;` to the css of the span element. After that you can adjust the padding of the span to suit and the text would remain centrally aligned in the span. Idea of using `display:table` to fix this problem taken from Cris J in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392211/html-span-align-center-not-working).